# Know Network Reciprocity From Scattering Matrix

Tags: passive-networks

Given the scattering matrix,  \begin{array}{l}0.25&0.80-0.80j\\0.80+0.80j&0.30\end{array}

Is this a reciprocal network?

I know that for a two port matrix, it is reciprocal when S<sub>21</sub>=S<sub>12</sub>.

In this case they are complex conjugates so they aren't really equal. Therefore, it seems like the network wouldn't be reciprocal. However, should the imaginary part of the complex number be compared anyway? The network doesn't seem to be generating any extra output so, in that definition of a reciprocal network, the current network described by this scattering matrix DOES seem to be reciprocal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No .

Although the phasor gains or |magnitudes| are equal in amplitude for forward and reverse , their phase shifts are not equal, so they do not satisfy the Reciprocity Theorem.